# Blender fluid simulation liquid particles leaking

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to make a fluid simulation and the particles keep leaking out at the side of the biggest box.

I have tried adding surface thickness, the particles stop generating after certain amount of surface thickness.

I also have solidify modifire added, but it also stops particles generating if i increase the Thickness on solidify.

Increasing Resolution divisons also did not work. How can i solve this?

[image: particles spilling out]

[image: mesh added for better view]

[image: solidify modifire]
[image: Flow settings]
[image: Domain Settings]

*edit: added screenshot of the flow cube and the effector.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Would you please elaborate how you have setup your simulation? Where does the liquid come from? From the cube in which it should stay? To emit liquid into the scene, the cube has to be set to _Flow_. To work as an obstacle for the liquid, the cube has to be set to _Effector_. It can only be one of those two. Or is there a hidden _Flow_ object somewhere?

Comment: maybe share your object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you, I added the screenshot of the flow and effector object. The liquid should come from the box with the blue particles inside. It is set to fluid type:  flow, flow behavior : geometry. Effector objects are selected four seperate object parented to arrows object and their faces that the liquid shoud flow are deleted.

Comment: In your cube you need a fluid::effector::collision to "hold" the fluid.  It  must have a thickness of at least 0.5